# spring boot mongodb audit gives duplicate collection error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

spring boot mongodb audit gives duplicate collection error. I'm trying to create dateCreate and dateUpdate fields when I insert and update a collection but when updated it gives the error:

> org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write operation error
> on server user.domain.com:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000,
> message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: springboot.category
> index: *id* dup key: { _id: "21" }', details={}}.

the execution is duplicating the key, below is my structure

My class AuditingConfig.java:

```
Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class AuditingConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> myAuditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

My class AuditMetadata.java:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class AuditMetadata {

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @Version 
    private Long version;

    // @CreatedBy
    // private String createdByUser;

    // @LastModifiedBy
    // private String modifiedByUser;
  
  //...getters and setters omitted
}
```

My class AuditorAwareImpl.java:

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of("Admin");
    }
}
```

My class entity CategoryMongo.java:

```
Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "category")
public class CategoryMongo extends AuditMetadata{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("category_id")
    private String category_id;
    
    @JsonProperty("id_colletion")
    private String emberId;

    public String getEmberId() {
        return category_id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("category_name")
    private String name;

 
    @JsonProperty("category_active")
    private ProductEnum active = ProductEnum.ativo;

    @JsonProperty("category_slug")
    private String slug;
 
    // @JsonProperty("category_updateAt")
    // @LastModifiedDate
    // private Date updateAt;

    // @JsonProperty("category_createdAt")
    // @CreatedDate
    // private Date createdAt;

}
```

My method save:

```
     CategoryMongo catm = new CategoryMongo();
            catm.setName(category.getName());
            catm.setSlug(category.getSlug());
            catm.setActive(category.getActive());
            catm.setCategory_id(category.getCategory_id().toString());
            catm.setEmberId(category.getCategory_id().toString());
categoryRepositoryMongo.save(catm);
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I solved the error I use in the document an interface follows the updated classes:

class AuditMetadata.java:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class AuditMetadata {

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @Version 
    private Long version;

    protected boolean persisted;

    // @CreatedBy
    // private String createdByUser;

    // @LastModifiedBy
    // private String modifiedByUser;
  
  //...getters and setters omitted
}
```

class Document CategoryMongo.java:

```
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "category")
public class CategoryMongo extends AuditMetadata implements Persistable<String>{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("category_id")
    private String category_id;
    
    @JsonProperty("id_colletion")
    private String emberId;

    public String getEmberId() {
        return category_id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("category_name")
    private String name;

 
    @JsonProperty("category_active")
    private ProductEnum active = ProductEnum.ativo;

    @JsonProperty("category_slug")
    private String slug;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String getId() {
        return category_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
         return !persisted;
    }
 
    // @JsonProperty("category_updateAt")
    // @LastModifiedDate
    // private Date updateAt;

    // @JsonProperty("category_createdAt")
    // @CreatedDate
    // private Date createdAt;

}
```

save method:

```
    CategoryMongo catm = new CategoryMongo();
    catm.setName(category.getName());
    catm.setSlug(category.getSlug());
    catm.setActive(category.getActive());
    catm.setCategory_id(category.getCategory_id().toString());
    catm.setPersisted(true);
    categoryRepositoryMongo.save(catm);
```

But something happens that I didn't want to happen: the @CreatedDate field disappears when I update it and only @LastModifiedDate appears in the result. if anyone knows how to solve this post here